# Git - find revision with tag that start with

Tags: git, format-patch

I want to do format-patch between the last revision that has a tag that start with "Sync_" and the HEAD

Something like:

```
git format-patch Sync_*...HEAD
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What if there are multiple tags matching the pattern? Which do you need?

Comment: @RomainValeri - thanks for the comment, I edited the question - I need the last one

Answer (score 0):

```bash
git format-patch $(git describe --no-abbrev --match='Sync_*')...HEAD
```

This finds the first reachable annotated tag with this pattern (glob) from `HEAD`.